# Custom plugin foreach wp_insert_post not working

Tags: plugin-development, wp-insert-post

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

Why not works?

My plugin: ~/wp-content/plugins/mypluggg/mypluggg.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: mypluggg
 */
    function videos() {
        // file_get_content()
        // $http_response_header
        $postarr = array();
        foreach( $videos as $key=> $video ) {
            $postarr [ $key ] = array( // etc.
            wp_insert_post( $postarr [ $key ], $wp_error );
        }
    }
    videos();
?>
```

Add 1 post and then error screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQAh4.png

There has been a critical error on this website.
[Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.](https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-troubleshooting/)

Why?

**UPDATE(1):**

```
foreach( $videos as $key=> $video ) {

    $postarr [ $key ] = array(

        'post_title'=> $videos [ 'title' ] [ $key ],
        'post_content'=> '<iframe src="https://*.com/' . $videos [ 'id' ] [ $key ] . '" frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no allowfullscreen=allowfullscreen></iframe>',
        'post_status'=> 'publish',
        'post_author'=> 1,

        'meta_input'=> array(

            'site'=> '*.com',
            'video_id'=> $videos [ 'id' ] [ $key ],
            'thumbnail'=> $thumbnail,
            'video_url'=> $video_url,
            'iframe_src_start'=> 'https://*.com/embedframe/',
            'iframe_src_end'=> '',
            'v_tag'=> $tag

        )

    );

}
```

**UPDATE(2):**

My ~/error_log file (I don't call is_user_logged_in function):

```
[31-Aug-2021 15:16:22 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in /home/x/public_html2/y/public_html/wp-includes/post.php:2793
Stack trace:
#0 /home/x/public_html2/y/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(7359): _count_posts_cache_key('post', 'readable')
#1 /home/x/public_html2/y/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): _transition_post_status('publish', 'new', Object(WP_Post))
#2 /home/x/public_html2/y/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#3 /home/x/public_html2/y/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#4 /home/x/public_html2/y/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(5098): do_action('transition_post...', 'publish', 'new', Object(WP_Post))
#5 /home/x/public_html2/y/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(4368): wp_transition_post_status('publish', 'new', Object(WP_Post))
#6 /home/x/public_html2/y/public_html in /home/x/public_html2/y/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 2793
```

**UPDATE(3):**

Is not working, I see the error screen (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQAh4.png):

```
$ID = wp_insert_post( $postarr [ $key ], $wp_error );
if( ! is_wp_error( $ID ) ) {} else {
    echo $ID-> get_error_message();
} else {}
```

**UPDATE(4):**

I try create my new test custom plugin, but the problem is the same. The full code:

~/wp-content/plugins/mypluk/mypluk.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: mypluk
 */

    function videoss() {

        $postarr = array();

        foreach( array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27 ) as $key ) {

            $postarr [ $key ] = array(

                'post_title'=> 'title' . $key

            );

            $ID = wp_insert_post( $postarr [ $key ], $wp_error );

        }

    }

    videoss();

?>
```

Comment: Can you fix your code example to include the missing sections? The values in `$postarr` are important.  also notice the code uses a `$wp_error` variable, but this variable isn't declared or defined. There is also no error checking. If `wp_insert_post` fails it returns an error object explaining why, but there is no check to see if this happens. Where does `$videos` come from?

Comment: @TomJNowell please see the UPDATE(1). If commented // wp_insert_post(); and I check the $postarr array, this array is fine.

Comment: have you made any modifications to the files in `wp-includes`?

Comment: Also, expect `iframe` tags to be stripped by security filters, you should use a shortcode instead or oembed of some kind

Comment: No. I work only this one file: ~/wp-content/plugins/mypluggg/mypluggg.php

Comment: Your use of `$wp_error` is incorrect. that's not how that function works. `wp_insert_post` will return a `WP_Error` object if it fails, and a post ID if it succeeds. You need to check if `$ID` is an error object, it is not a true/false value. And get rid of `$wp_error`, that's not how `wp_insert_post` works

Comment: I try without iframe, but not work: 'post_content'=> 'test: ' . $videos [ 'title' ] [ $key ],

Comment: i recommend reading the documentation for `wp_insert_post` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/ there are lots of examples, including how to check for failure https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#comment-2096

Comment: I try, but not works: if( ! $ID ) { die( var_dump( $wp_error ) ); } else {} I see the same error screen: https://i.imgur.com/MlxcTsW.png

Comment: Like I said, get rid of `$wp_error`, that's not how that function works. Look at the documentation, it has examples showing you how to check for `WP_Error` objects and print the error message. Screenshots of the generic "There has been a critical error" message are useless. Can you update your questions code so that it contains a complete code example? Not partial or separated examples. How are you running this code? Show us the entire contents of `mypluggg.php`

Comment: I try, but not works: if( ! is_wp_error( $ID ) ) {} else { echo $ID-> get_error_message(); } I see the same error screen: https://i.imgur.com/MlxcTsW.png

Comment: The first $postarr array wp_insert_post is okay, but need more 26 posts in foreach loop. Why only the first? First post added, and see the error screen.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, update your question to contain the complete and full code, not snippets, and read the document I linked to. It has examples that show you the correct way to do this

Comment: @TomJNowell please see the UPDATE(4). This is full code. Please test. It only adds 1 post in the same way: title1 (post_title)

Comment: I think the problem is the foreach loop... What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I could see it from your code and the error logs, is that your plugin is calling [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) *too early*, which is before functions like [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) is defined or before the file it's defined is loaded, which by the time you call `videos()` or `videoss()` (which calls `wp_insert_post()`), that file has not yet been loaded and thus, PHP threw the fatal error which says "*Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in()*".

> My ~/error_log file (I don't call is_user_logged_in function):

Yes maybe you didn't, but then, `wp_insert_post()` called [`wp_transition_post_status()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_transition_post_status/) and if you examine the *stack trace* in the error log entry, what happened is:

1. `wp_transition_post_status()` fired the `transition_post_status` hook.
2. Then that hook called one of its registered callbacks, which is `_transition_post_status()`.
3. And finally, that function called [`_count_posts_cache_key()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_count_posts_cache_key/) which is the one that called `is_user_logged_in()`.

And in response to your comment: (* I formatted it for brevity)

> The first `$postarr` array `wp_insert_post` is okay, but need more 26
> posts in `foreach` loop. Why only the first? First post added, and see
> the error screen.

The reason why the first one worked is because the post was already added to the database **before** the post status is transitioned, but the other (26) posts could not be created because after `wp_transition_post_status()` is called, PHP threw the above fatal error and therefore WordPress displayed the [error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQAh4.png).

#### So how can you solve the problem?

It's basically simple: Use a hook like [`plugins_loaded`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/), [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) or [`wp_loaded`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_loaded/) to run your `videos()` or `videoss()` function (you got two plugins in the question) and don't simply call the function which would be the same as you calling `wp_insert_post()` directly from the root in the main plugin file.

So for example using the `init` hook, in `mypluggg.php`, call `videos()` like so:

```php
add_action( 'init', 'mypluggg_create_posts' );
function mypluggg_create_posts() {
    videos();
}
// or yes, this would work as well..
//add_action( 'init', 'videos' );
```

However, note that `init` (and the other 2 hooks mentioned above) runs on each page load, so you might better off look for another approach to create the posts you wanted to create, e.g. you could use a [cron job](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) or [WP-CLI](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/), but that's another story. :)

Additionally, if you want `wp_insert_post()` to return a `WP_Error` instance/object if the post creation/update didn't succeed, then set the 2nd parameter to `true` like so: `wp_insert_post( $postarr[ $key ], true )`, or you could use `$wp_error`, but make sure that variable is defined. E.g.

```php
$wp_error = true; // here, define it

foreach ( $videos as $key => $video ) {
    $postarr[ $key ] = array( ... );

    // pass $wp_error as the 2nd parameter
    $id = wp_insert_post( $postarr[ $key ], $wp_error );

    if ( is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
        error_log( 'Error creating post! Message: ' . $id->get_error_message() );
    }
}
```